# python. как сделать, чтобы несколько графиков не соединялись линиями?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть датафрейм. по нему хочу построить несколько графиков.

```
0  2020-12-01 00:00:00  cчетчик, акт. прием  171.6  7200201311
1  2020-12-01 01:00:00  cчетчик, акт. прием  166.5  7200201311
2  2020-12-01 02:00:00  cчетчик, акт. прием  168.0  7200201311
3  2020-12-01 03:00:00  cчетчик, акт. прием  165.3  7200201311
4  2020-12-01 04:00:00  cчетчик, акт. прием  160.2  7200201311
..                 ...                  ...    ...         ...
67 2020-12-01 19:00:00  cчетчик, акт. прием  298.2  7200226151
68 2020-12-01 20:00:00  cчетчик, акт. прием  308.1  7200226151
69 2020-12-01 21:00:00  cчетчик, акт. прием  313.8  7200226151
70 2020-12-01 22:00:00  cчетчик, акт. прием  310.8  7200226151
71 2020-12-01 23:00:00  cчетчик, акт. прием  309.0  7200226151
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: добавил скрин к вопросу

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1251554/edit))

Comment: у вас один датафрейм, соответственно, график тоже один